# Jquery Validate EqualTo Issue

Tags: jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code

```
  $("#emailForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "UserPasswordReset.EmailAddress": {
            maxlength: 256,
            email: true,
        },
        "UserPasswordReset.ConfirmEmailAddress": {
            maxlength: 256,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#UserPasswordReset.EmailAddress"
        }
    }
});
```

When I fill in the below form and press submit I says on the confirm box please enter the same value so I check, double check and for the love of god I check again, but still I get please enter the same value even though both fields are identical.

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1-1"> Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input id="emailaddress" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" type="text" value="" name="UserPasswordReset.EmailAddress" data-val-required="The EmailAddress field is required." data-val="true" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please enter your email address">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1-1"> Confirm </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input id="confirm_email" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" type="text" value="" name="UserPasswordReset.ConfirmEmailAddress" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please confirm your email address">
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btnSaveEmail" class="btn btn-info pull-right" type="Submit" value="true" name="SaveEmailAddress"> Update Email </button>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ConfirmEmailAddress` rule has

```
equalTo: "#UserPasswordReset.EmailAddress"
```

You don't have a control with `id="UserPasswordReset.EmailAddress"` (only one with `id="emailaddress"`). Change it to

```
equalTo: "#emailaddress"
```